# Stunnel on ubuntu fails to listen on the port

Tags: stunnel

I have installed stunnel4 on my 16.04 ubuntu and I have not been able to get any result out of the specific ports I have set it on via netstat -tulnp | grep 4444
here is my service status :

```
    stunnel4.service - LSB: Start or stop stunnel 4.x (SSL tunnel for network daemons)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/stunnel4; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-02-22 22:16:54 CET; 4s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2397 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/stunnel4 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 22 22:16:54 Hypothesis stunnel4[2397]: [!] Cannot open log file: /var/log/stunnel14/stunnel.log
Feb 22 22:16:54 Hypothesis stunnel4[2397]: [ ] Closing service [squid]
Feb 22 22:16:54 Hypothesis stunnel4[2397]: [ ] Service [squid] closed (FD=7)
Feb 22 22:16:54 Hypothesis stunnel4[2397]: [ ] Service [squid] closed
Feb 22 22:16:54 Hypothesis stunnel4[2397]: failed
Feb 22 22:16:54 Hypothesis stunnel4[2397]: You should check that you have specified the pid= in you configurat
Feb 22 22:16:54 Hypothesis systemd[1]: stunnel4.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 22 22:16:54 Hypothesis systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start or stop stunnel 4.x (SSL tunnel for network
Feb 22 22:16:54 Hypothesis systemd[1]: stunnel4.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 22 22:16:54 Hypothesis systemd[1]: stunnel4.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

my conf file :

```
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
pid = /var/run/stunnel.pid
setuid = root
setgid = root
output = /var/log/stunnel14/stunnel.log
[squid]
accept = 4444
connect = 127.0.0.1:54321
```

My stunnel.pid is present in the respective folder and yet I get that error message aside from that , it seems weird for me to see in the log , stunnel is trying to close squid

how can over come these errors ?

Comment: I'd worry more about that error involving the log file `/var/log/stunnel14/stunnel.log`.

Comment: The `stunnel14` part of `Cannot open log file: /var/log/stunnel14/stunnel.log` looks like a typo in the configuration file.  Otherwise check `/etc/stunnel/stunnel4.conf` for the `chroot` option and modify either the `output` option or the `chroot` option.